# How to get the current state i.e. ChangeSet/UUID/version-number of a project/file by using RTC Java APIs 5.2

Tags: java, rtc, svnkit

How to get the current state i.e. ChangeSet/UUID/version-number of a project/file  by using RTC Java APIs 5.2 (residing on Jazz server) along with its contents.

> Suppose I load a particular file into my local sandbox, then I deleted
>   that file from my local workspace/sandbox, And  other developer
>   checked-in the changes into the same file, so How to get that file
>   previous contents ignoring the latest state updated by someone else???

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you reload your local sandbox (based on your repo workspace), you would recover that file (without any further modification)

You would get the other developer work only if you accepted incomming change sets into your repository workspace.
If you didn't accept anything, simply reloading would be enough.
(as illustrated in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/118483/rtc-v401-java-api-how-to-load-a-workspace-using-java-api), using `ILoadOperation`)

Comment: Thx Vonc for replying.

Comment: ...But the problem is I am running my programs by outside the Eclipse, so how to load that project..I can ask then..How to load a folder again created sometimes before but deleted accidentally!!!

Comment: @Kishore Eclise plays no role in loading a sandbox. It only load the .project (if found) in its *Eclipse* workspace. To load a sandbox (a folder with a `.jazz5` in it), you don't need Eclipse. The `ILoadOperation` I mention in the answer is unrelated to Eclipse.